# How can I prevent my Bootstrap banner from wrapping to next line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am working on a top banner with Bootstrap and my condensed menu always is wrapping to a new line for 1024x768. This is working well for resolution greater than 1024x768. Please advise in correcting my html so that the banner stays fixed on the top for 1024x768 resolution.
The banner text has to be centered, the logo should be on the left and logged in user name should be on the right.

```css
.headerBackGroundColor {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top headerBackGroundColor">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Title" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-header navbar-brand">
    Application Title on Banner Goes Here
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-nav nav navbar-right">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" style="cursor:default !important;">
      <span class="user-name">
        Welcome loggedInUser
       </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you expect to happen when the three items don't fit? Also, posting a message like your greeting in a button is bad practice. You should use elements for their intended purpose for usability and accessibility. The fact that you felt the need to override cursor behavior is a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

Does this look good to you?

```css
.headerBackGroundColor {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top headerBackGroundColor">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row w-100 justify-content-md-around row-cols-3">
      <div class="col-lg-auto">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Title" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-auto d-flex align-items-center">
        <div>Application Title on Banner Goes Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-auto d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="navbar-nav nav navbar-right">
          <buttonclass="btn btn-default" type="button" style="cursor:default !important;">
            <span class="user-name"> Welcome loggedInUser </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```